# Proof: the resolvent operator is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I tried to prove that the resolvent operator $$\rho(A) \to \mathbb C,\space \lambda \mapsto R_{\lambda}(A):=(\lambda id_X -A)^{-1} $$
is holomorphic, where here $A$ is a bounded linear operator from the complex Banach space $X$ into itself and $\rho (A)$ denotes the resolvent set. Let's assume we already know that the map $\lambda \mapsto R_{\lambda}(A)$ is continuous and that the resolvent set is open in $\mathbb C$.

My strategy was using an equivalence proved before in the script namely that a operator valued function $A: \Omega \to L(X,Y)$ ($\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ open and $X,Y$ complex Banach spaces) which is continuous, is even holomorphic if and only if the map $ \Omega \to \mathbb C, \space z\mapsto \langle y^*,A(z)x\rangle$ is holomorphic for every $y^*$ in $Y^*$ and every $x$ in $X$.

Observe in our case this map is 
$$ \rho(A) \to \mathbb C , \space \lambda \mapsto \langle x^*,(\lambda id_X-A)x\rangle$$

and by some computation
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\langle x^*,((\lambda+h) id_x-A)x\rangle - \langle x^*,(\lambda id_x-A)x\rangle} h\ = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(\lambda+h)\langle x^*,x \rangle -\langle A^*x^*,x\rangle - \lambda \langle x^*,x \rangle + \langle A^*x^*,x \rangle}h\  = \langle x^*,x \rangle  $$

which is then a constant function for every $x$ and $x^*$ we pick and in particular holomorphic. q.e.d.

My questions:

Did I apply the equivalence result the right way? Is there an easier way to obtain the same result? Is my computation/proof even correct?

Comment: You proved $\lambda \mapsto \lambda I -A$ is holomorphic, with the expected derivative $I$. That's not what you want. Do you know the resolvent equation?

Comment: oh yeah I forgot to invert it. Yes I know the proof with the resolvent equation.

Comment: If you know the local series expansion for the resolvent, that's a good candidate for applying the weak definition in order to conclude that the series is holomorphic in $\lambda$. That reduces to the case of a complex power series from an operator power series. You can first bootstrap up to a vector power series and then to the operator power series.